# Ubuntu 10.04 nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia

I've just downloaded and installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a Asus N43S laptop with Geforce GT 550M CUDA 1GB.

However the only screen resolution I can take is 1024*768.

System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers, does NOT show me anything that could be installed.

I am all out of options at the moment, any help appreciated!

Have a great evening!

- Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the latest nvidia drivers using the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: I ended up reinstalling. Thanks though!