# Nautilus file names are not visible after LibreOffice invocation

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nautilus, libreoffice, nvidia-optimus

When I open a LibreOffice text document in Nautilus, and then close it, the line within Nautilus that lists the document appears to be highlighted, and in my case it is pink highlighting.  There is no text visible within the highlighting so the name of the file is not visible.  This appears to be a new feature or bug since I've never noticed this before.

Normally, when files are selected in Nautilus, I see them highlighted in a sort of brown colour with text in "reverse video".  After the file open/close operation, this is no longer the case and instead of brown, it is pink highlighting, and text is not visible.

How can I fix this?

Details:

12.04 LTS with updates to approximately mid-August 2013.

Hardware:

Samsung RF711 laptop with the Nvidia GeForce GT540M with Optimus.  I do not currently have a Nvidia-specific driver enabled.

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have, and do you have graphics drivers enabled?

Comment: I get the same issue sometimes with my nVidia chip. It's due to a buggy driver blob.

Comment: My hardware details have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The update procedure at this link solved the problem for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72155/ubuntu-10-04-nvidia-drivers)

The procedure:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`